# Сгруппировать по свойству объекта с помощью reduce

Tags: javascript

Сгруппировать объекты по возрасту

```
let users = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },
  { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
];

// Ожидаемый результат:
{23: 1, 28: 2, 34: 1}
```

И надо индексировать объекты по id

```
let users = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },
  { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
];

Ожидаемый результат:
{
  11: { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
  47: { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },
  85: { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },
  97: { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
}
```

Мои попытки:

```
 let usersResult = users.reduce((acc, i) => {
  if (i.age === i.age[acc]) {
    console.log("i.age");
  } else {
    console.log("i.age[acc]");
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

// тут не знаю как вывести id перед {}
let usersResult = users.reduce((acc, i) => {
// ? i.id 
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: Домашнее задание нужно делать самостоятельно

Comment: Добавьте код, где видно, что вы пытались решить задачу самостоятельно

Comment: let usersResult = users.reduce((acc, i) => {
  if (i.age === i.age[acc]) {
    console.log("i.age");
  } else {
    console.log("i.age[acc]");
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

Comment: @ChupaYupa, код нужно добавлять в вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы группировать по возрасту, просто проверяем было ли установлено значение для `ac[cu.age]`, если да, то увеличиваем на 1 для каждого объекта.

```js
const users = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },
  { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
];

// 1. Сгруппировать объекты по возрасту
console.log(
  users.reduce((ac, cu) => 
    (ac[cu.age] === 1 ? ac[cu.age]++ : ac[cu.age] = 1, ac),{})
);

// 2. Индексировать объекты по id
console.log(users.map(e => ({ [e.id]: e })));
```

Comment: а второй можно с помощью reduce тоже сделать?

Comment: а зачем? тот же эффект. Тем более что такие вещи принято мапом делать.

Comment: для закрепления reduce

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]